# Get a uri from a LocalStorage in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, storagefile

I write the following code to save some images from internet:

```
    public static async Task SaveImage(string name, string uri)
    {
        var localfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var imageStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri); //Secuencia de bytes
        var storageFile = await localfolder.CreateFileAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (Stream outputStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await imageStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
        }
    }
```

My problem is when I try to set these images store in the Local Storage to a CycleTile because this class needs the Uri's, and I don't know how to provide the uri here. This is what I have:

```
        CycleTileData cycleicon = new CycleTileData();
        cycleicon.Title = "Fotopantalla";
        cycleicon.Count = 0;
        cycleicon.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileSmall.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        List<Uri> images = new List<Uri>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            /// tries...
            string path1 = "ms-appdata:///local/image" + i + ".jpg";
            string path2 = "isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/image" + i + ".jpg";
            string path3 = "ms-appdata:///Local/Shared/ShellContent/image" + i + ".jpg";
            ///

            Uri uri = new Uri(path2, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            images.Add(uri);
        }

        cycleicon.CycleImages = images;
```

What am I wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Actually, that should work (path 2 or 3). Have you checked with WP Power Tools or some other Isostorage tool if the downloads worked okay?

Answer (score 0):

For any ShellTileData related data structures you have to use path2:
"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/*" if the images are not in the (read only) InstalledLocation folder.

For more details see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/04/10/live-apps-creating-custom-tile-and-lock-screen-images.aspx

I have something similar in my code:

```
var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (!store.DirectoryExists("Shared/ShellContent"))
{
    store.CreateDirectory("Shared/ShellContent");
}
StorageFolder shellContent = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Shared", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
shellContent = await shellContent.CreateFolderAsync("ShellContent", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

Stream imgin = picture.GetImage(); 
//Picture read stream from Media Library or other input stream

StorageFile new_img = await shellContent.CreateFileAsync(newPictureName);
Stream imgout = await new_img.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

imgin.CopyTo(imgout);

imgout.Close(); // <- necessary in your code or not?
imgin.Close(); // <-
```

I'm not sure, whether you really need the Isostore thing at the beginning, but it works, if I haven't done some stupid mistake while shortening the code. ;-)

Also have a look at "StandardTileData.BackgroundImage Property", "Data for Windows Phone" and "How to use the Isolated Storage Explorer tool for Windows Phone" from Microsoft's Dev Center. (The last one is about how to have a look at the saved image file on your device.)